# how to run service forever in Oreo+

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-service, android-jobscheduler

I want to run a service in backround forever in android 8(Oreo) and above.
but my service does not run forever it just run until my app is running.
I tried jobscheduler, job intent service,foreground service and background service with BroadcastReceiver but when I destroy the app service will destroy too

this is what I want to run forever:

```java
package ir.daneshja.www.alarm;

import android.app.Service;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.DisconnectedBufferOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class AlertService extends JobIntentService {
    public MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

    final String serverUri = "tcp://**.**.***.***:1883";

    final String clientId = "qgpwexnp-12345";
    final String username = "*****";
    final String password = "*******";
    public boolean issubs;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(AlertService.this, serverUri, clientId);
        connect();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(AlertService.this, R.raw.alert_sound);

        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Log.e("mqtt", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.e("Mqtt", mqttMessage.toString());
                if (mqttMessage.toString().equals("alarm") || mqttMessage.toString().equals("alarm\n\r")) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("alert", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isalerting", true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                while (true) {
                    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    };

                    thread.start();
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("alert", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    boolean donNotPlayAgain = prefs.getBoolean("stopalert", false);
                    if (donNotPlayAgain) {
                        thread.stop();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                        thread.start();
                    }
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("alert", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isalerting", false);
                editor.apply();
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
        connect();
    }


    private void connect() {
        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setUserName(username);
        mqttConnectOptions.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

        try {

            if (!mqttAndroidClient.isConnected()) {
                mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                        DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                        mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                        Log.e("issub", String.valueOf(issubs));
                        subscribeToTopic("alert");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        Log.e("Mqtt", "Failed to connect to: " + serverUri + exception.toString());
                    }
                });


            }
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void subscribeToTopic(String topic) {
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(topic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.e("Mqtt", "Subscribed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.e("Mqtt", "Subscribed fail!");
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exceptionst subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

thanks.

Comment: Not doable, you need to have a foreground service.

Comment: "I want to run a service in backround forever in android 8(Oreo) and above" -- that is not supported, sorry. As Pawel points out, use a foreground service. Even that is not guaranteed to run forever, but it is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: What do you mean with _when I destroy the app service will destroy too_? If you remove an app from the recent apps, you'll also kill the process, thus the service with it.